# Suspend vs Screen Lock

Tags: suspend, power-management, lock-screen

If I have the "Brightness & Lock" settings enabling "screen lock" after x minutes, but the Power settings set to "never suspend", does that mean the machine will "sleep" or not?

It seems like a long running process is being paused when I check back on it after a screen lock, even though the machine isn't supposed to suspend...

Should be disabling screen lock too in order to ensure this process can finish while the machine idles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tried it while running a YouTube song in the background. Even after the screen got locked the song kept playing. Machine didn't switch to sleep.

So, yes. Screen Lock after 'X' minutes, just locks the screen but the process keeps going on unless the system sleeps.

*PS: I don't have enough points to post a comment so, had to post this as an answer. Hopefully it helps.*

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good test.  It must just look like that on the massive build process I'm running.  I gave you an up vote and accepted answer, to boost your standing.